# Parent-child v/s multiple indexes - Elasticsearch 6.2+

Tags: elasticsearch

We currently have a ES 5.3 cluster which uses parent-child mapping as our data follows this model. Parent-child mapping was the best option as it supported cluster-side joins and provided performance benefits from being stored in the same shard.

Migration from 5.3 to 6.2 involves breaking changes as multiple mapping types are no longer supported from ES v6.0 onwards.

Wondering if it's worth sticking to parent-child data model in newer versions of elasticsearch using join data types.

From what i know, there are three possible options

1. Retain parent-child mapping using the new join data type.

   **Pros**

   - Cluster-side joins
   - Performance benefits
   - Can still use has_parent, has_child queries

   **Cons**

   - Flat mapping schema (gets ugly if the document have lot of properties)
   - Difficult to identify the type just by looking at the document
2. Create separate index for each mapping type

   **Pros**

   - Mapping looks much cleaner
   - Easy to identify the type of document just by looking at it
   - Can make use of routing to put all related child documents of a parent in the same shard
   - Each index can have different shard configuration (flexibility)

   **Cons**

   - Requires a common field in both index to maintain relationship
   - Cannot use has_parent, has_child queries anymore
   - Requires application-side joins
   - Child index can get very big compared to parent index
   - Multiple queries to perform the join can increase the overall latency
3. Single index but with a custom field to define type of the document

   **Pros**

   - No need to use join type
   - Can make use of custom routing to put related documents in the same shard

   **Cons**

   - Mapping looks complicated
   - Index can get very big as all the documents will reside in the same index

I'm more leaned towards the second option of having multiple indices. The main downside i can see is that application-side joins can be expensive. At the same time, elasticsearch documentation says has_parent, has_child queries are also expensive.

The other advantage of parent-child documents of being stored in the same shard can be achieved to some extent by having individual indices use routing and hence achieve data locality with in the respective indices.

> **Current cluster stats**
>
> 270492501 total docs
>
> 1596009 parent docs
>
> 268896492 child docs
>
> Parent:child doc count ratio can be at most 1:400
>
> 36 total shards (12 primary, 24 replicas)
>
> 92.33 GB data
>
> Parent docs are read heavy. Child docs are read and write heavy.

Would like to know if there's any other performance/scaling aspect i need to consider. Thanks

Comment: "elasticsearch documentation says has_parent, has_child queries are also expensive" this should be a different order of magnitude. I'd only use application side JOINs if you have to  — it's more work for your app and will (generally) have the worst performance.

Comment: @xeraa kind of feel the same but i'm wondering if parent-child can give the same benefits if the index keeps getting bigger. Was not able to find any benchmark tests online.

Comment: Benchmarks are really tricky — just for this use case it will depend on the number of children, the size,... And if the shards are getting too big, you need more of them. Can you give an indication for the data size and number of read and write queries? Please add it to the original question.

Comment: yea, totally agree. updated the question with details you asked

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to benchmark that for your data, your hardware, your queries,... I guess you have 3 nodes (at least) and with 3 copies I wouldn't expect major issues with that datasize. Though I'd lean towards parent-child

Comment: Currently, cluster have 12 nodes (i3.4x large) with 3 dedicated masters. I’m also considering denormalizing the data and keeping just one index to avoid joins.